# Trouble Getting Twitter Gem To Work - Giving Undefined Method Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-gem

I am following along with the documentation for the Twitter gem and trying to get some results, but I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `sample' for nil:NilClass
```

I've put this in my config/initializers/twitter_credentials.rb (my keys and tokens are filled in my app)

```
@client = Twitter::Streaming::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY"
  config.consumer_secret     = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
  config.access_token        = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
  config.access_token_secret = "YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET"
end
```

Here are bits from my controller:

```
require 'twitter'

class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @tweets = Array.new
    @client.sample do |object|
        @tweets << object.text if object.is_a?(Twitter::Tweet)
    end
  end
end
```

This is in my view:

```
<% @tweets do |tweet| %>
   <%= tweet.text %>
<% end %>
```

And of course, this is in my gemfile:

```
gem 'twitter'
```

Why am I getting that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was referencing it using an instance variable (e.g. `@client =` ), when I needed to make it a constant or a global.

Answer `CLIENT =`

The other option was to put it instantiate the client within the controller.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, 'sample' is not define.

```
@client.sample do |object|
```

Comment: Try to put your "Configuration works" and "Stream a random sample of all tweets" in same controller.